# JPanel, BorderLayout works wrong

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, render, jlabel

Well idc what i did but now everytime i start the program my screen just split into right side and left side, and i wanted them to merge and just put the red in the east side of the screen and its just like.. split into 2 panels ..
im trying to make a world editor for my lwjgl game and i want to make a panel, that render my game on the area with the red screen on it, but i just cant put it in the right place
here is a picture - http://prntscr.com/85o1es
as you can see for some reason there is 2 screen there, i colored the panel in gray and u can see the panel is only on the right side... the rendering of the display is fine, red background and a model of a black square
if someone knows why my screen splits plz help.

```
public class Panel
{

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static Canvas glCanvas = new Canvas();
    private JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    private static Loader loader;
    private static Renderer renderer;


    public static void gui()
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1280, 1024);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        gui();
        setCanvas();
        DisplayManager.createDisplay();
        loader = new Loader();
        renderer = new Renderer();

        float[] vertices =
        { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,

        0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f };

        RawModel model = loader.loadToVAO(vertices);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            renderer.prepare();
            renderer.render(model);
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

    }

    private static void setCanvas()
    {
        glCanvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        glCanvas.setSize(720, 480);
        panel.add(glCanvas);
        try
        {
            Display.setParent(glCanvas);
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to

```
 frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

this

```
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

why did you set position to `BorderLayout.EAST`?. set it to center .

what you see as split panel in left side is your jframe .because of you have set border-layout constrain to east your panel has positioned at the right side . 
if you not sure put

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
```

and you will see it's the frame.

---

edit.......

according to your comments you want to position your canvas at right bottom

so 
add panel to East as you already done

```
 frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

set panel layout to `border layout`

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and add canvas to south of the panel

```
panel.add(glCanvas,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: i thought thats how i put my display on the east side... i want my display on the right south area for example.. how can i do that?

Comment: @noam what ? display on the right south area ?can you clarify little

Comment: sure. as you can see i got a gray color on the panel and i got my red square that render my game (not atm but will in the future) http://prntscr.com/85obug 
so i want to take that display (it called display in the code btw) and put it in the right south area of the window

Comment: @noam do you want position black panel out of the red canvas ? or you want to position at right botom of the red panel.sorry

Comment: The black square inside of the red canvas is my model, its ok. its rendering in there just fine, what i want is to place the red canvas on the right south area of the screen (the gray area).

Comment: no... again.. the black square is my model. it suppoes to be inside of the red canvas..i want the red canvas and the model inside of it (the black square) to be on the right side south

Comment: @noam plz can you draw what you want like i did ?then i can surely understand sorry

Comment: http://prntscr.com/85okrm, simple way to say it - i want my canvas on the right south area of the screen

Comment: @noam i think you want something like this http://prntscr.com/85op7y .am i right ?

Comment: yes that is what i want, u know how to fix my code maybe?

Comment: @noam check out updated answer and tell me if it work or not

Comment: its like this now http://prntscr.com/85p0nh , i know i can put a variable that will choose if i want it to be on the left or right, how can i do that? cuz atm its just stretch all over the screen

Comment: @noam no no i told you `add panel to East`  `frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);` you probably leave it as center

Comment: when i change it to east it looks like that.. http://prntscr.com/85p38q 
its like i have another panel there cuz its not in gray color im 100% sure u can choose if u want it left or right somehow

Comment: @noam yes there is a panel .so you have to set panel color to the jframe .then you can't see there is a panel.
add this line `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);`